# Complete the words

Tags: mathematics, cipher

Actually these puzzles have been made by me two years ago, but I've made it easier and faster to finish by reducing the calculation operation.

```
        A,B,C,D,E,F G,H,I J,K,L,M,N,O,P

  3,15,14(E),20,18,15,12,12,5,4  2,25 20,8(A),5

            19,9,20,21,1,20,9,15,14

       5,14,22,9,18,15,14,13(C),5,14,20

                 1,14,4

         9,14,6,12,21,5,14,3,5

B - C = A
C + D = E
F - G = H
I + J = K
K = B
E - C = G
K - G = O
J = L = M
O - G = P
C - A = I
```

Find what number represents to A, B, C, etc.

Comment: As clear-cut a case of self-plagiarism as I've ever seen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numbers are

> The usual mapping between numbers and letters (1 = A, 2 = B, ...), yielding:
>  CONTROLLED BY THE
>  SITUATION
>  ENVIRONMENT
>  AND
>  INFLUENCE

Taking the letters in parentheses to be

> the values of the neighboring letters in the system of equations, we get:
>  A = 8, B = 21, C = 13, D = 1, E = 14, G = 1, I = 5, J = 16, K = 21, L = 16, M = 16, O = 20, P = 19, with F = H + 1 and N not determined.

Translating the first line in the same way as before, we get

> HUMAN? A?E PUPP?TS

Filling in the remaining gaps and putting everything together, we get

> HUMANS ARE PUPPETS CONTROLLED BY THE SITUATION ENVIRONMENT AND INFLUENCE
>  (which tells us F = 19, H = 18, and N = 5).